# play framework: activator start stops unexpectly

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

My Play project works properly with `activator run` command. but when I am using `activator start` command, after packaging the application starting stopped unexpectly with following error:

```
.
.
.
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.0 ...
  [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Wrote E:\workspace\CustomerClub\target\scala-2.11\customerclub_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources and 50 Java sources to E:\workspace\CustomerClub\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] Main Scala API documentation to E:\workspace\CustomerClub\target\scala-2.11\api...
model contains 93 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging E:\workspace\CustomerClub\target\scala-2.11\customerclub_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[warn] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] Packaging E:\workspace\CustomerClub\target\customerclub-1.0-SNAPSHOT-assets.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging E:\workspace\CustomerClub\target\scala-2.11\customerclub_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

'"E:\java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe" -version 2>&1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The batch file cannot be found.
```

I quess that it is from my JDK or JRE, but executing this command has result:

```
E:\workspace\CustomerClub>"E:\java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe" -version 2>&1
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

- Environment variable like `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` are setted.
- I am using Java 8 with window 7 64 bit edition

Comment: Just to confirm, what does `echo %JAVA_HOME%` show?

Comment: the response of `E:\workspace\CustomerClub>echo %JAVA_HOME%` is: 
`E:\java\jdk1.8.0_05`

Comment: The only place I've found `java.exe -version 2>&1` is LibreOffice source code, but it would be very strange if it would have have anything to do with your error. I had myself issues with activator and Java 8 and switched to Java 7. Maybe you could run activator with it?

Comment: No! I am using java 8 grammar in my source code

Comment: With removing java 8 codes , and testing with lava 7 and java 6 problem exists yet.